# Oracle SQL -- Pick Max Value from RN Function but update all fields with that value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, rownum

My query is as follows

```
SELECT HEADER_TABLE.SEGMENT1,
       LINES_TABLE.LINE_NUM,
       CASE
          WHEN (    HEADER_TABLE.REVISION_NUM = '0'
                AND HEADER_TABLE.PRINT_COUNT = '0')
          THEN
             'Unavailable'
          ELSE
             NVL (ACK_TABLE.ACK_TYPE, 'Absent')
       END
          AS X_ACK_TYPE,
       ACK_TABLE.GXS_DATE
  FROM HEADER_TABLE,
       LINES_TABLE,
       (SELECT po_number,
               po_line_number,
               gxs_date,
               po_ack_filename,
               ack_type
          FROM (SELECT po_number,
                       po_line_number,
                       gxs_date,
                       po_ack_filename,
                       ack_type,
                       ROW_NUMBER ()
                       OVER (PARTITION BY po_number ORDER BY gxs_date DESC)
                          rn
                  FROM xxcmst_po_ack_from_gxs_stg)
         WHERE rn = 1) ACK_TABLE,
       (SELECT PO_NUMBER FROM XXCMST.XXCMST_ACTION_TABLE_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT) ACTION_TABLE
 WHERE     HEADER_TABLE.PO_HEADER_ID = LINES_TABLE.PO_HEADER_ID
       AND HEADER_TABLE.SEGMENT1 = ACK_TABLE.PO_NUMBER(+)
       AND HEADER_TABLE.SEGMENT1 = ACTION_TABLE.PO_NUMBER(+)
       AND LINES_TABLE.LINE_NUM = ACK_TABLE.PO_LINE_NUMBER(+)
       AND HEADER_TABLE.SEGMENT1 = '100';
```

This is giving me 6 records with 1 GXS_DATE and X_ACK_TYPE = 'Absent'. The RN function is needed here to pull 1 record only from the subquery but the requirement is to have all the 6 records have the same date and ACK_TYPE which is not happening. How can I achieve this? Please refer to the below screenshot and I need X_ACK_TYPE = AK for all the 6 LINE_NUMs and GXS_DATE = 3/6/2020 for all these 6 records.

[My current data screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpePo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ACK_TABLE.GXS_DATE
```

in `SELECT` clause use the `LAG` function as follows:

```
CASE WHEN ACK_TABLE.GXS_DATE IS NOT NULL 
     THEN ACK_TABLE.GXS_DATE
     ELSE LAG(ACK_TABLE.GXS_DATE IGNORE NULLS) 
                OVER (PARTITION BY HEADER_TABLE.SEGMENT1 ORDER BY LINES_TABLE.LINE_NUM )
END AS GXS_DATE
```

or If there will be always one value of `ACK_TABLE.GXS_DATE` exists per `HEADER_TABLE.SEGMENT1` then you can simply write it as

```
MIN(ACK_TABLE.GXS_DATE)
    OVER (PARTITION BY HEADER_TABLE.SEGMENT1) AS GXS_DATE
```

**-- Update --**

for `ACK_TYPE`, You need to apply the same logic in `ELSE` portion of your CASE statement from the original query as follows:

Replace this:

```
ELSE
    NVL (ACK_TABLE.ACK_TYPE, 'Absent')
END
```

With this:

```
ELSE
    NVL (MIN(ACK_TABLE.ACK_TYPE)
           OVER (PARTITION BY HEADER_TABLE.SEGMENT1), 'Absent')
END
```

Comment: Thanks @Tejash, it almost works.. I am getting the GXS_DATE populated for all 6 rows but still the same X_ACK_TYPE is coming. The X_ACK_TYPE should be what is coming from source which is AK for my case here.. but in the case statement somehow its populating 'Absent' for the other 5 records..  How do I get X_ACK_TYPE = 'AK' for all 6 records? 

2565095 1 AK                  3/6/2020
2565095 5 Absent          3/6/2020
2565095 2 Absent          3/6/2020
2565095 3 Absent          3/6/2020
2565095 6 Absent          3/6/2020
2565095 4 Absent          3/6/2020